# How to center all the elements of separate tables HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website where there are four titles above four images and four descriptions below. For both the titles and descriptions, I have used/created two different tables. The images are placed accordingly using margins. The tables look good on my computer but when transferred to a larger screen they move to the left. I figured out that the way to make them compatable and look good on all larger screens would be to centre the tables. I have tried using align: centre for the table and including style="text-align: centre;" but neither have worked. How can I fix this problem. Thanks for any help in advance. It is greatly appreciated. Below is my current code:

```css
.mobile_title {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 105px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.text_under {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  width: 150;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.laptop {
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.coding {
  margin-left: 155px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.database {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 45px;
}

.load {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 130px 10px;
}

.kbg {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 155px 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table class="load">
    <tr>
      <td class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</td>
      <td class="mobile_title">Web Development</td>
      <td class="mobile_title">Backend Development</td>
      <td class="mobile_title">Database Creation</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <img src="mobile.png" width=160 height=120 class="mobile">

  <img src="laptop.png" width=150 height=100 class="laptop">

  <img src="coding.png" width=150 height=100 class="coding">

  <img src="database.png" width=150 height=110 class="database">

  <table class="kbg">
    <tr>
      <td class="text_under">The creation of applications for iOS and Android devices. This also includes the mobile optimization of websites, making them responsive on all devices.</td>
      <td class="text_under">The creation of web-based sites using multiple programming languages including HTML, CSS, and Custom word press. These websites, after the creation stages, are hosted online for all to observe.</td>
      <td class="text_under">The process and supporting information that websites need in order to perform wanted tasks. The information is written in codes, the process called programming.</td>
      <td class="text_under">The location of storage of all of the supporting information. This also saves all important files including the back ends of developing websites and/or mobile applications.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Tables for sites are so 90s

Comment: @dippas.        I agree with you. Couldn't figure out how to do this any other way though

Comment: have you heard about flexbox? just an example

Comment: @dippas.       I had but was told that tables would be most reliable for this job

Comment: why are not you using div for such formatting ?

Comment: I hope you tried to Google something before you went to ask this question. Anywhere on the web, even including w3schools, you would've found the usage of `<div>` with basic percentage or flexbox styling. Please, for the love of all that is not `<table>`, Google! (Hint: `<div><picture></picture></div>`)

Comment: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/) is a great resource

Comment: So is [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Nukeface.      Thanks for help. Found flex boxes and seems like a much better solution. Was told previously on stack overflow that tables would be an good option to solve this problem.

Comment: They are. They may not be the easiest/most intuitive to learn, but sure are worth knowing. I can think of only one (type of) scenario of using tables, and that's displaying structured data. Say an index page in an administrator environment, listing all User (as an example) by id, username, email, etc. Then it'd be easy/handy/*meh, might as well*. In any other scenario that (might) require different resolutions/view ports/browser types, use flexbox or "old-fashioned" `<div>'s` with % width marking.

Comment: @myfunkyside On w3fools I notice references to resources such as: [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/), [W3C](http://www.w3.org/), [Web platform docs](http://www.webplatform.org/), [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/) and others (IRC channels and contributors).

Comment: Should I now sum up all the useful things one can find on w3schools? It's a lot

Answer (score 0):

as per my comment, using flexbox it is easier than tables.

```css
.load-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  /*to center - optional */
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto
}

.load {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box
}

.mobile_title {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.text_under {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: grey;
}

.mobile {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="load-wrap">
  <div class="load">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/160x120" class="mobile">
    <div class="text_under">The creation of applications for iOS and Android devices. This also includes the mobile optimization of websites, making them responsive on all devices.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/160x120" class="mobile">
    <div class="text_under">The creation of applications for iOS and Android devices. This also includes the mobile optimization of websites, making them responsive on all devices.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/160x120" class="mobile">
    <div class="text_under">The creation of applications for iOS and Android devices. This also includes the mobile optimization of websites, making them responsive on all devices.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="load">
    <div class="mobile_title">Mobile Development</div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/160x120" class="mobile">
    <div class="text_under">The creation of applications for iOS and Android devices. This also includes the mobile optimization of websites, making them responsive on all devices.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I put margins in between the pictures and text. I tried using margin right and left  but doesn't work

Comment: @Kg123 try `margin-top:30px` in `.text_under` (if I understood what you want) (`30px` or any other value you want)

Comment: Wrote wrong thing above. How could I place margins to the side of the pictures and text so there is more space in between horizontally

Comment: @Kg123 you need to apply `padding` to `load` see updated answer/snippet

Comment: I added padding but it doesn't seem to work. I need it to stretch out longer accross the screen. It is to compact in middle

Comment: have you read this in my answer? `/*to center - optional */  width: 75%;
  margin: auto`

Comment: I had but didn't understand what it meant

Comment: Ok, I will remove it

Answer (score -1):

Put your images in new row with each image in separated column, also do that for description text. And to center images use:

```
td img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

For centering text add:

```
text-align: center;
```

In your .load class.

Here is your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9c1p3fm6/

Edit: And yes, you need to delete all classes you attached to img elements.

Comment: Hvala puno. Greatly appreciate the help

Comment: @Kg123 Nema na cemu. You could mark it as solved than :)